# Rails how to rewrite this old route map.connect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wsdl

How do I rewrite this old route Rails 1.2.6 to Rails 3? :

```
  # Allow downloading Web Service WSDL as a file with an extension
  # instead of a file named 'wsdl'
  map.connect ':controller/service.wsdl', :action => 'wsdl'
```

I can´t see how I should use match route etc.

I have used:

```
  match ':controller/service.wsdl', :action => 'wsdl'
```

But I dont think it is working correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
match '/controller/service.wsdl' => 'controller#service.wsdl', :as => :wsdl
```

I'm guessing that your controller is not named controller.  If it is, I'd rename it and change the above route as well.

Comment: I dont have a controller named controller. I don´t understand how I then should create the route. I cannot found any controller with the action service.wsdl

Comment: Here's an example.  Let's say that you have a controller called posts_controller.rb.  In that controller, you'd have a method (action) named wsdl (def wdsl … end).  In that method, you have the code that you want to execute.  In that case, the above route would be:  match '/posts/wsdl' => 'posts#.wsdl', :as => :wsdl.  You could then have a link_to("WSDL, wsdl_path) in your views.

Comment: I am updated a website from rails 1.2.6 to rails 3 and there is this route that leads to nowhere.

Comment: Then you don't need it.  Just comment it out with a #

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good solution to converting Rails 2 parameterized :controller and :action generic routes to the more explicit Rails 3+ format.  What I've had to do is go through every permutation in my app and add an explicit route for everything I needed to support.  For example, in your case, if you had 3 controllers that supported the wsdl action, I'd add a new route for each using either match or get.

Here's what it might look like, assuming you had a foo_controller, bar_controller, and a blah_controller that all support the wsdl action:

```
get '/foo/service.wsdl' :to => 'foo#wsdl'
get '/bar/service.wsdl' :to => 'bar#wsdl'
get '/blah/service.wsdl' :to => 'blah#wsdl'
```

This gets even more fun when you need to support every action on a controller when they use :action.

If anyone has a better method, I'm open (and eager) to hear of a better way.